# Abstract interpretation of isomorphism between tensor product with dual and hom

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules, sheaf-theory

I'm interested in the following statement, coming from Remark 6.4.21 of Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*:

> Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ be quasi-coherent sheaves on a scheme $X$. Then we have a canonical homomorphism $\mathcal{F}^\vee \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ which on any affine open subset $U$ sends $\phi \otimes y \in \mathcal{F}^\vee(U) \otimes \mathcal{G}(U)$ to the homomorphism $x \mapsto \phi(x)y$. It is easy to verify that it is an isomorphism if $\mathcal{F}$ or $\mathcal{G}$ is locally free.

Here $\mathcal{H}om$ denotes the internal hom functor.

My question is how to understand this isomorphism in an abstract sense, by appealing to a map defined in terms of something like a tensor-hom adjunction. Since everything is well-defined in terms of (locally free) sheaves, I'd expect it to be something canonical, i.e. not requiring a choice of basis. (Since even in the case of line bundles, we don't have the isomorphism $\mathcal{L} \simeq \mathcal{L}^\vee$). How should I think about this?

**EDIT:** as the comment by Zhen Lin points out, the map is canonical in that it is choice free. I suppose I'm looking for an abstract characterization of the map as an instance of some more abstract categorical property.

In addition, why does the locally free assumption come in? I'm not sure if in this context, locally free means of locally constant rank (i.e. free on some open cover) or just free at every point. The latter seems necessary in order to describe why the map is an isomorphism on stalks, but I don't see why the former would come up.

Comment: As stated, $\mathscr{F}^\vee \otimes \mathscr{G} \to \mathscr{H}om (\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G})$ _is_ canonical. You can describe it abstractly if you like. What _does_ require work is showing that it is sometimes an isomorphism.

Comment: I guess canonical isn't exactly the word I was looking for: I meant to ask if this map comes from some abstract categorical property?

Comment: Yes, it does. Isn't that what I said? You might like to think about how to do it in, say, the category of modules over a commutative ring.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but isn't the map as described perfectly well-defined in (say) an abelian category? I'm looking for something like saying that $\phi \otimes x \mapsto (x \mapsto \phi(x) y)$ is some adjunction/other similar categorical thing applied to $\mathcal{F}^\vee \otimes \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: No, you can't do it in an abelian category. You need a symmetric monoidal closed category – and in fact that's all you need to define the morphism. Showing that it is (sometimes) an isomorphism is not abstract nonsense, however.